# Vaadin 23 disable individual cell selection in Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Is it possible to disable individual cell selection in the Grid component.

Right now, I added:

```
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

but still able to select individual cell, like on the screenshot below:

[image]

I need to allow only entire row selection. Is it possible to configure this in the Grid component?

Comment: What you're seeing is not selection, but cell focus. Right now I don't have access to a computer where I could try out exactly what would work, but the official documentation has a section on Cell Focus with an example that night help get some idea on how to target the visual representation using CSS. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#cell-focus

Comment: Thank you! Right now I fixed my issue in the following way - I merged two columns into the single one. So right now my grid looks like Accordion, but this is exactly what I need))